# c - converting a pointer to const int into pointer to just int (and modyfing it)

Tags: c, pointers, casting

good people of the Internet!

Throughout my newbee journey across stormy lands of C i found this piece of code:

```
void * add (void * _set, const void *_element)
{   int * set = _set;
    const int * element =_element;
    assert(set > heap && set < heap +MANY);
    assert(* set ==MANY);
    assert(element >heap && element < heap +MANY);
    if (* element == MANY)
        * (int *) element = set — heap;
    else
        assert(* element == set —heap);
    return (void *)element;
}
```

In this piece of a code, `heap` is an array of `int`s, `MANY` is a macro for an integer literal, and the whole idea is to store an index of some element of `heap` in `element` (or check if it is already there). `_set` and `_element` are presumed to be pointers to `heap`'s elements.

The question is - how come they can firstly say that an `_element` points to const something, then make a new pointer `element` that point to `const` `int`, and then just cast it into pointer to regular `int` and then just modify this `int`? Isn't is some bad forbidden magic?

Thank you in advance, kind sirs!

Cheers!

Comment: If you ask about every nonsensical thing you find in horrifically broken C code you find in a trashcan, you'll spend a lot of time covered in people's intellectual bankruptcy.

Comment: @EOF -  I am not sure why "newbee journey" word combination haven't signalised you that I am not yet any good in distinguting "horrifically broken C" from something that i probably just don't know or understand yet, but thank you for pointing that it is a bad practice to use code from an example above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If an object was **defined** with `const`, then the C standard does not define the behavior of attempting to modify it.

However, if an object was defined **without** `const`, you can make a pointer to it, add `const` to that pointer, and later remove `const`. For example, the following has well-defined behavior:

```
int x = 3;

// Fine, make a pointer to x:
int *p = &x;

// Copy into a `const int *`.
// Compiler accepts adding `const` without complaint:
const int *cp = p;

// Copy into an `int *` without `const`.
// Requires a cast because the compiler would complain without it:
int *np = (int *) cp;

// Change x, which was not defined with `const`.
*np = 4;

// Prints 4:
printf("%d\n", x);
```

A scenario in which this is used is where a library providing certain features creates an object and wants the client not to modify it. So it allocates spaces for the object and gives the client a `const`-qualified pointer to it. (Although the client **can** modify the object by using a cast to remove `const` as shown above, it is trusted not to—this technique is to prevent innocent mistakes, not to prevent intentional malice.) Later, when the library wants to modify or deallocate the object, it may use a pointer it receives back from the client and use a cast to remove the `const` qualifier.